# Can cosine similarity be applied to multidimensional matrices?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, clustering, similarity

I'm trying to find the similarity between two 4D matrices. Because cosine similarity takes the dot product of the input matrices, the result is inevitably a matrix. Is there a way to get a scalar value instead? Could inner product used instead of dot product? That is, is

`cossim(A,B) = inner(A,B) / (norm(A) * norm(B))`

valid? Or is there a better way to find the similarity between multidimensional matrices?

Comment: Well, this depends very much on how the similarity is defined: there is no general definition thereof: what is the question you are trying to answer? When would you want two matrices to be "close" to each other?

Answer (score 4):

Don't hack. Do the math instead.

You could reshape your matrix into a vector, then use cosine.

But whether that is *sensible* to do: ask yourself.

You could also ignore the matrix and always return 0. That is a proper similarity, too. Just usually not useful.

Don't just use some function because you heard the name. You need to understand it's properties, and *you* need to check whether these properties are helpful for your problem, or not. Choose one because math says this is solving your problem; don't replace the math with random guessing.

- [Cosine similarity link 1](http://blog.christianperone.com/2013/09/machine-learning-cosine-similarity-for-vector-space-models-part-iii/)
- [Cosine similarity link 2](https://cmry.github.io/notes/euclidean-v-cosine)
- [Cosine similarity link 3](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/ml-clustering-and-retrieval/distance-metrics-cosine-similarity-yyegc)